# Is there a way to force order of letters when using replaceall()?

Tags: java, replaceall

I want to filter out a string like this in a link: (The link is not exactly like this, much longer).

```
https://www.(whatever).com/junk/section39843**no2938**.
```

- I need to get no(number) as a String.
- When trying to use `replaceAll("[^no0-9]","")`
  to remove everything other than no(number), I get on39843no2938.

Is there a way to leave ONLY "no" with all the numbers? Numbers are fine, because I'm searching through with contains().

Comment: So, the URL ends with `no`followed by digits, and you want those digits? Why use replaceAll to do that. Why not just find the last index of `no`, and then take the substring starting from that index + 2? You regex replaces everything that is not (n, or o, or a digit). So you end up with all the n, o, and digits in the URL.

Comment: The link would have multiple nos, that was just a simplified version. It's actually really long. Wouldn't this be a problem? I'll make an note of this in the question.

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us what you **really** want to achieve.

Comment: Basically, I need to extract String of a link, no(numbers) to compare it to another string which is no(numbers[generated]) to see if it matches. There are multiple generated links that have no(numbers) in them. I was thinking of filtering out what I need with replaceall, but if there's a way to extract exactly what I need please let me know.

Comment: Again, I can't if you don't explain precisely what you want to extract from what. What do your URLs **actually** look like? What is their **precise** format. And what do you **precisely** want to extract? Give precise examples of inputs and outputs.